# SQL Server 2008 query plan warns "No Join Predicate", query takes very long time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Here is my SQL

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d, Company c1 
WHERE 

EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('HENNEPIN COUNTY MN', ',')) as s     
        WHERE c1.CompanyName like '%' + s.items + '%' AND d.CustomerID  c1.CompanyID)
OR  
EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('HENNEPIN COUNTY MN', ',')) as s     
        WHERE d.CustomerName like '%' + s.items + '%')
```

In sort, it is misinterpreting the OR as a Cartesian product, you can read here:  http://www.scarydba.com/2009/09/15/no-join-predicate/

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results? How are Device and Company related? Perhaps you should use a UNION / UNION ALL instead of  what looks to me like a CROSS JOIN anyway?

Comment: Do Company and Device not relate to eachother?  Can you `from device d join company c1 on d.companyid = c1.companyid` ?

Comment: As Tom said, the problem is that Device and Company are not joined with a predicate. The OR isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insight Phil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d, Company c1
```

But you're not joining `Device` and `Company` in any way.  As a result, you'll get every record from `Device` paired to every record from `Company` and get the number of records in `Device` times the number of records in `Company` returned.

Since you're only returning the fields from `Device`, no wonder you need the `DISTINCT` and no wonder it's taking so long.

If that's what you really do want, you can get rid of that message by using the `CROSS JOIN` operation:

```
select d.*
from   Device d
   CROSS JOIN Company c1
```

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more about the CROSS JOIN operation.

But we can probably make this faster.  Try this:

```
 ;
 WITH s AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   [dbo].[Split] ('HENNEPIN COUNTY MN', ',') s
 )  
 SELECT  d.*
 FROM    Device d
 WHERE   EXISTS ( 
            select * 
            from   s
                JOIN Companies c1
                   ON c1.CompanyName like '%' + s.items + '%' 
           where d.CustomerID = c1.CompanyID
        )
    OR  EXISTS (
           select  *
           from    S
           where   d.CustomerName like '%' + s.items + '%'
        )
```

That could probably be further improved, but given that I don't know for certain what problem this query is trying to solve, that's the best I can do for now.